# How to create local file link in description section of work item within Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, workitem

I am trying to create a link to a local file within the description section of a task in Azure DevOps.

I have tried using the extension file:///H:\Documents\test.xlsx The link appears as a hyperlink, however it is not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create local file link in description section of work item
> within Azure Devops?

I am afraid this is not achievable in Azure devops. The description section of the work item cannot add the link associated with the local file.

You can [attach local files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/share-plans?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#attach-files) as attachments to work item.

Choose the `Attachment` tab icon to attach a file with supplemental information.

[image]